# Uppercase and comma in \cite and parenthesis in \citeonline

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like the quote to look like this:

`\cite` should give `(VECCHIO et al., 2017)` and not `(Vecchio et al. 2017)`

and

`\citeonline` should give `Vecchio et al. (2017)` and not `Vecchio et al. 2017`

I'm using the following commands in the compiler:

```
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf,abnt-repeated-title-omit=yes,abnt-emphasize=bf,abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}
```

I'm using the following compiler: pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pcall-tcc/dywydszxydqd. And the document class is abntex2

Answer (score 1):

Just delete that part

```
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}
```

Now it's working.